# VHDL problems with parity check

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying to make an atomic clock based on the DCF77 signal. Now I'm trying to do an even parity check on a vector. When it's ok than pass the right data to another vector.
Now my problem is that it won't do the parity check (for-loop with xor inside), for me the code is correct and there are no errors with compilation.

```
parity: process(reset, clk, start)
begin
    if((reset /= '1') or (start /= '1')) then
        if(falling_edge(clk)) then
            if(count >= 58 and start = '0' and data(38) = '1' and data /= x"1FFFFFFFFFFFFFF") then -- if every data has arrived and minute mark1 = 1                
                par <= '0';
                for I in 37 downto 31 loop -- loop over every bit of the minutes and count how many logical 1 bits there are
                    par <= par xor data(I); -- check minute parity
                end loop;

                if((par = '1' and data(30) = '1') or (par = '0' and data(30) = '0')) then -- if the minute parity is correct then proceed to hour parity else reset the whole time data
                    par <= '0';
                    for I in 29 downto 24 loop -- loop over every bit of the minutes and count how many logical 1 bits there are
                        par <= par xor data(I); -- check hour parity
                    end loop;

                    if((par = '1' and data(23) = '1') or (par = '0' and data(23) = '0')) then  -- if the hour parity is correct then proceed put data to a seperate vector else reset the whole time data
                        dataTime <= data(37 downto 23);
                    else
                        dataTime <= (others => '1'); -- Error
                    end if;
                else
                    dataTime <= (others => '1'); -- Error
                end if;

                par <= '0';
                for I in 22 downto 1 loop -- loop over every bit of the date and count how many logical 1 bits there are
                    par <= par xor data(I); -- check date parity
                end loop;

                if((par = '1' and data(0) = '1') or (par = '0' and data(0) = '0')) then
                    dataDate <= data(22 downto 0); -- load the date data in to a seperate vector
                else
                    dataDate <= (others => '1'); -- Error
                end if;
            else
                dataTime <= (others => '1');
                dataDate <= (others => '1');
            end if;
        end if;
    else
        dataTime <= (others => '1');
        dataDate <= (others => '1');
        par <= '0';
    end if;
end process;
```

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parity is calculated using a signal for `par`, but in VHDL the read value
of a signal is not update until after a delta cycle.  So accumulation through a
signal in the loop is not possible with a process evaluated only at the clock
edge.

One possibility is to make the `par` a process variable, and use `:=` for
assign to the variable, since VHDL variables are updated immediately for read.
Code:

```
parity: process(reset, clk, start)
  variable par : std_logic;
begin
    ...
                par := '0';
                for I in 37 downto 31 loop
                    par := par xor data(I);
                end loop;
    ...
```

A final `par := '0';` in the reset part is not necessary, since `par` is
initialized before each iteration.

An alternative in VHDL-2002 is to create an reduction XOR function, with code
like:

```
  function xor_reduct(slv : in std_logic_vector) return std_logic is
    variable res_v : std_logic;
  begin
    res_v := '0';
    for i in slv'range loop
      res_v := res_v xor slv(i);
    end loop;
    return res_v;
  end function;

begin

    parity: process(reset, clk, start)
      variable par : std_logic;
    begin
        ...
                    par := xor_reduct(data(37 downto 31));
```

In VHDL-2008 (if supported) it is:

```
par := xor data(37 downto 31);
```